# Could life exist in a universe, in which the roles of "stars" and interstellar space were reversed?

Tags: habitability

I was thinking of a universe, in which "stars" range in temperature from 5 degrees Kelvin to 10 degrees Kelvin, while gas in interstellar space has a temperature of 6000 degrees Kelvin.

Could life exist in this universe?

Comment: What is the matter density? Are the stars still much denser than the gas surrounding? Or is that flipped around as well, with a gigantic mass of gas with a few tiny specs of near vacuum?

Comment: The stars would still be denser than the surrounding gas.

Comment: How is this not simply describing Jupiter?

Comment: How are the 'stars' being cooled? How is the gas  being heated? And are we requiring hard science here or can we use a lot of hand-waving to explain how this universe got this way?

Comment: This question rests on a false premise: that the interstellar vacuum of space somehow contains 6000K worth of energy, all the time, and that *somehow* that energy doesn't *bake the living daylight* out of the 10K stars.  Space isn't cold, space is *empty.*  This has the effect of making objects incapable of heating up *or* cooling off: there are no molecules filling the void to transfer heat energy *with.* All you're left with is black body radiation (which does transfer energy, but directly in proportion to its own: hot objects radiate more).

Answer (score 4):

## No

With this 5–10K the stars can't do nuclear fusion, they won't produce light, *heat* and much less... **higher elements** (like Ni, Fe, Br, C, O, etc). The universe would be only H2 and with H2 you can't have even planets (much less life...).

Also, I am not sure but starts would solids (H2 smelt at 14K and boil at 20K)

About nebulas (interstellar gas) I don't know anything, but these nebulas would be made of H2 (stars won't produce other materials), so planets would be gas giants and they can't have *our* life forms (there will be gaseous planets).

Comment: Would the temperature of the intestellar space be insufficient to cause fusion?  I don't know how much temperature matters and how much pressure matters, but interstellar space is a *gargantuan* volume.  Even at its terribly low density, there might be enough mass out there to fuse higher atoms by sheer probability alone.

Comment: @CortAmmon I have seen a science movie where said that Hydrogen need 10.000.000C and in Wikipedia it say that Starts use 14.000.000K to make H2 fusion. Both numbers are bigger than 6.000K ---> **no fusion**.

Comment: Good point.  When the OP said that the roles of stars and ISM were reversed, I naturally assumed the temperature for ISM was going to be that of the stars and didn't fact check myself.  I should have noticed that the temperature the OP chose was the surface temperature (where no fusion occurs), rather than the core temperature.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming such a universe could exist, the only matter would be hydrogen and helium at best. Possibly, the only element in this universe could be hydrogen which won't improve the probability of life. @EnderLook is quite right there would no nuclear fusion and consequently no stellar nucleosynthesis to produce other elements.

There will be no life in this universe -- unless life can evolve at extremely low temperatures and if it is composed entirely of hydrogen and helium. This seems highly improbable. The situation is only worse in a hydrogen-only universe.

Also, there doesn't seem to be any probable mechanism for a universe filled with cold stars and a hot vacuum.